# How to evaluate $\int\frac{x-1}{(x+1)\sqrt{x^3+x^2+x}}\,dx$

Tags: integration

How to evaluate the following pseudo-elliptic integral?

$$\int\frac{x-1}{(x+1)\sqrt{x^3+x^2+x}}\,dx$$

I think that I should make $(x+1)^4$ and substract something under the square root. I got $(x+1)^4 -x^4-3x^3-5x^2-3x-1$ but I have no idea what I should do with summands.

Comment: answer in the book is arcsin((x^2+1)/(x+1)^2)+C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$$\int\frac{x-1}{(x+1)\sqrt{x^3+x^2+x}}\,dx\\~\\＝\int\frac{(x-1)(x＋1)}{(x+1)^2\sqrt{x^3+x^2+x}}\,dx\\~\\＝\int\;\frac {x^2-1}{(x^2＋2x＋1)\sqrt{x^3+x^2+x}}dx\\~\\＝\int\;\frac {x^2-1}{(x^3＋2x^2＋x)\sqrt {x＋1＋\frac {1}{x}}}dx\\~\\\int\;\frac {1-\frac {1}{x^2}}{(x＋2＋\frac {1}{x})\sqrt {x＋1＋\frac {1}{x}}}dx$$

Now : let u=$x+\frac{1}{x}$

Comment: Thank you so much for helping

Comment: Can you show me how to start proving my last third question please? I really need your help. It's my last request

Answer (score 8):

Apply the Euler substitution $\sqrt{x^3+x^2+x}=xt$. Then, $t^2=x+1+\frac1x$, $dx= \frac{2tx^2}{x^2-1}dt$ and
$$\int \frac{x-1}{(x+1) \sqrt{x^3+x^2+x}}dx
=\int \frac2{t^2+1}dt=2\tan^{-1}t+C
$$

Comment: I'm confused. we use Euler substitution when we have (ax^2+bx+c) under square root. arcsin((x^2+1)/(x+1)^2)+C is answer in the book

Comment: @James - Note that $$2\tan^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{x^3+x^2+x}}x-\sin^{-1}\frac{x^2+1}{(x+1)^2}=\frac\pi2$$ They differ by a constant

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2):

Take the argument from the book as the argument transformation and consider the square (as one should do always with elliptic integrals, signs may be considered later on).

In Mathematica in order to avoid trival transfer errors

```
       Solve[(x^2 + 1)/(x + 1)^2 == y, x] // FullSimplify
       {{x->(y+Sqrt[-1+2 y])/(1-y)},{x->(-y+Sqrt[-1+2 y])/(-1+y)}}


      ((dx (x - 1)/((x + 1) Sqrt[x] Sqrt[x^2 + x + 1])))^2 //. 
        {x -> (y + Sqrt[-1 + 2 y])/(1 - y), 
         dx -> D[(y + Sqrt[-1 + 2 y])/(1 - y), y] dy} // FullSimplify

         dy^2/(1 - y^2)
```

This yields the $\arcsin$ with domain and inversion of the map in the complex domain open to discussion. Real line integrals are always given as half definite integrals with lower or upper limits pinned to one of the branch points of the square roots. The indefinite integrals have an algebraical local meaning only.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $x=\dfrac{1-y}{1+y}$ then $z=y^2+1$ :

$$\begin{align*}
& \int\frac{x-1}{(x+1)\sqrt{x^3+x^2+x}}\,dx \tag1 \\
&= \int \frac{2y}{\sqrt{\frac{(1-y)^3}{(1+y)^3} + \frac{(1-y)^2}{(1+y)^2} + \frac{1-y}{1+y}}} \, \frac{dy}{(1+y)^2} \\
&= \int \frac{2y}{\sqrt{3-2y^2-y^4}} \, dy \\
&= \int \frac{2y}{\sqrt{4-\left(y^2+1\right)^2}} \, dy \\
&= \int \frac{dz}{\sqrt{4-z^2}} \tag2
\end{align*}$$